# How to Clear this "Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.ts(8010)" error in VSCODE

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio, nestjs, typescript-eslint

I am using nest js as my backend and i get this type annotation error often. I am unable to solve this error. The file extension by default is .ts file. I even get this error when i use React with typecript. Is there any other options to solve this problem without disabling the validation.

[image]

I have tried disabling the typescript validation as some of the articles and Q&A suggest. But whats the use of disabling it when we use the typescript. I tried reinstalling the typecript and ESLInt too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your language in the bottom right window angle is set to TS
[image]

---

What exactly you did to lose it? you haven't provided links to what you did

Comment: As you said, I have changed the language at the bottom and it worked. It was previously with Javascript react. Thanks !!